# Particular Query not running in PHP(using PDO)

Tags: php, pdo

The below php code runs a query for which i get `$res = true` which means that the query should have run.
I checked the health of the PDO object also to make sure and found out that other queries get run correctly.
Also no exception were caught. Have run out of ways to solve this issue.

```
function insertPaypalSavedSanity($udi, $isPaypalSaved){
    global $DBH;
    try {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO sanity(user_id, saved_paypal_used_previously) VALUES(:user_id,:sv) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE saved_paypal_used_previously=:sv";
        $sqlcon = $DBH->prepare($sql);
        $res = $sqlcon->execute(array(
            'user_id'=>$_SESSION['userID'],
            'sv'=>$isPaypalSaved));//$res is true after executing the query
        $x = 1;// I put the debugger at this point and run other queries with my PDO object($DBH)
    } catch(Exception $e)
    {
        logger ("sanity queries",$e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Check what `$_SESSION['userID']` contains, it may be updating a different record than your expecting.  Also - try not to use `global`, if you need the connection in this function, pass it in.

Comment: @NigelRen the $_SESSION['userID'] is set correct. Also this function is called from 2 places in my code. When called from one place it works correct. In the other case no change to the database is reflected.

Comment: So it would be useful to show the code where it's called from.  The code as you say works, but it's the context which seems to make a difference.

Comment: even after execution of the query the data is persisted corrected in PDO but not in the database.

Comment: Ok, this got solved by adding start transaction to beginning of statement and commit to the end of statement -                     $sql = "start  TRANSACTION;INSERT INTO sanity(user_id, saved_paypal_used_previously) VALUES(:user_id,:sv) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE saved_paypal_used_previously=:sv;COMMIT;";

Comment: Anyone can tell me why it wasnt ok earlier @NigelRen (a transaction isnt neccessary to make a query work)

Comment: Check for inconsistent use of transactions.  Using a transaction round the query will only change the effect if something else gets rolled back (or not committed).  So look in both branches and see if either uses transactions.  You could also check if you have autocommit set in your configuration.

Comment: ok ill have a look, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got solved by adding start transaction to beginning of statement and commit to the end of statement. I still have no clue as to why this worked.